# Hibernate and @SessionAttribute

Tags: spring, hibernate

Hibernate not updating SessionAttribute parameter.

I populated an entity object and put it in SessionAttribute with a name *editGroup*. I changed it on jsp page and sent to the controller. In controller I just call service method and give him object from session(*editGroup*). But entity object not updating.

*Controller*

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = "editGroup")
@RequestMapping(value = "/group")
public class GroupController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String groupEdit(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        if (!model.containsAttribute("editGroup")) {
            model.addAttribute("editGroup", groupService.findGroup(id));
        }
        return "group/editGroup";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String groupUpdate(@ModelAttribute("editGroup") Group editGroup,
            @PathVariable Long id, SessionStatus status) {
        groupService.updateGroup(editGroup);
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/group/" + id;
    }
}
```

*Service* *@Transactional*

```
public void updateGroup(Group obj) {
    groupDAO.update(group);
}
```

*DAO*

```
public void update(T obj) {
    getSession().merge(obj);
}
```

Hibernate even not sends request. Help me please.

Comment: Make sure that your service is transactional, without a transaction nothing gets to the database.

Comment: @M. Deinum, Service is transactional. I updated the post.

Comment: There is a `@Transactional` annotation that doesn't make it transactional. If you don't have a `<tx:annotation-driven />` it doesn't do anything or if you are scanning for the same component twice it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: What is your `getSession` method do?

Comment: @M.Deinum, It is a custom superclass's method. It just returns the currentSession by SessionFactory.

Comment: Please add the content of that method to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer on my issue.

I had the `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in a spring configuration. After specify the transaction-manager parameter in this one, program running properly.

`<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>`